# Как отбросить из DataFrame значения, составляющее менее 5% от общего числа?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В датасете в колонке представлены следующие значения

```
MICROLOANS                    25910

DL                           20200
ДО ЗАРПЛАТЫ 0107              18191
УНИВЕРСАЛЬНЫЙ НАЛИЧНЫМИ       15328
18_УНИВЕРСАЛЬНЫЙ НАЛИЧНЫМИ    12451
                              ...  
PIP1                              1
"0-0-6"                           1
Аннуитет на карту-2               1
TR01                              1
КРЕДИТ "0-0-0-10"                 1
Name: Тип займа, Length: 313, dtype: int64
```

Некоторые из них встречаются лишь единожды и статистически не значимы. Я бы хотел отбросить все значения, которые не составляют 5% от общего числа данных.

Я написал для этого функцию

```
def drop_less_signification_values(df_, col):
"""
Отбрасываем статистически не важные признаки (меньше 5% от общего числа)
"""
    counts = df_[col].value_counts(normalize=True)
    return df_[df[col].isin(counts.gt(0.05).index)]
```

После преобразования размер остается тем же

```
df['Тип займа'].count()
176289
df = drop_less_signification_values(df, 'Тип займа')
df['Тип займа'].count()
176289
```

В чем моя ошибка? Если какой то другой вариант, чтобы сделать это?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил изображения

Comment: вот здесь `counts.gt(0.05).index` а надо  `counts[counts.gt(0.05)].index`

Comment: @splash58 Да, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Тоже была эта ошибка, надо так сделать:

```
def drop_less_signification_values(df_, col):
    counts = df_[col].value_counts(normalize=True)
    return df_[df[col].isin(counts[counts.gt(0.5)].index)]

df = pd.DataFrame(['a','a','a','b'], columns=["col"])
df
  col
0   a
1   a
2   a
3   b

res = drop_less_signification_values (df, "col")
res
  col
0   a
1   a
2   a
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]